# How to properly highlight alternating rows after Filtering / Sorting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have this Excel sheet with about 2,000 rows of data :

[image]

I've applied a handful of Filters on Comparison Result & Extension, then added a few Sorting parameters for all of the columns.

If I then go to Conditional Formatting --> New Rule:

`=MOD(ROW(),2)=0` and set a fill color, it fills alternating even rows. The problem is that this is going by the "hard" row number, rather than actually alternating in real time after the filter is applied (for lack of a better way to put it).

So in the sample screenshot, both rows 888 and 890 are even and 'pass' the Conditional Formatting Rule to be highlighted. But they're displayed in succession, so really they **shouldn't** be highlighted.

How can I change the rule to only highlight alternating displayed rows?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a table, which would maintain the alternating row color scheme automatically?  (Genuine question - I don't understand what filters do that tables don't do)

Comment: Try a table then, instead of a filter (in Excel 2007, select your raw data, including headers, Then select Insert --> Tables -->Table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a table will accomplish what you are after:
 Excel 2007, select your raw data, including headers, Then select Insert --> Tables -->Table  (Shown in the upper-left corner of the attached image)

[image: Sample table]

Notice that in the table, I have filtered out some of the data (row numbers are not continuous) but the alternating color scheme is automatically preserved.